# JasperReports: Change font size by Param value

Tags: jasper-reports

```xml
<style name="blueStyle" >
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($P{INDIRIZZO}).length()>30 ?  Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE]]></conditionExpression>
        <style  style="blueStyle"  fontSize="3"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<parameter name="INDIRIZZO" class="java.lang.String"/>

[...]

<textField>
    <reportElement x="178" y="94" width="157" height="17"/>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{INDIRIZZO}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I want to downsize the font when ***INDIRIZZO*** length is > 30...

But this didn't work....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to apply your custom style to the *textField*.

The correct snippet will be:

```xml
    <textField>
        <reportElement style="blueStyle" x="178" y="94" width="157" height="17"/>
        <textElement>
            <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{INDIRIZZO}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

My working sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="conditional_styl" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="style1" forecolor="#66FF66" backcolor="#009966">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{parameter1}.length() < 2]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FFCC00"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT DOCUMENTID FROM POSITIONS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DOCUMENTID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="style1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Another working sample with ***fontSize*** modifying:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="conditional_styl" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="style1" fontSize="6">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID} % 2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontSize="8"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID} % 3 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontSize="10"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID} % 5 ==0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontSize="12"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID} % 7 ==0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontSize="14"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID} % 11 ==0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontSize="16"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID} % 13 ==0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontSize="18"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT distinct DOCUMENTID FROM POSITIONS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DOCUMENTID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="style1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="34"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Nothing happened. I made tests with iReport. Is this the reason? To check if iReport evalutate correctly the conditionals, I used it such as text Field like :    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{INDIRIZZO}.length()>30 ? "VERO" : "FALSO"]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: I've just add sample to my post. You can try this sample with demo db built-in in iReport

Comment: Yes, you can test report with iReport

Comment: I tried your example and it works.. But I try to add a new fontSize nothing happen.. Now.. I'm sure that iReport didn't work correctly.. Now I try to deploy and test

Comment: Add another sample with *fontSize* modifying

Comment: May be your style is corrupt. `<style  style="blueStyle"  fontSize="3"/>` - this string looks not good

Comment: Is there a setting to change font globally?

Comment: Do you mean something like default style for all reports?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use styled text to allow the text size to by changed dynamically. Set the textElement markup to `styled` and then add wrap a `<style>` tag around the contents of the textFieldExpression.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="150" height="13" />
    <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <textFieldExpression>
        <![CDATA["<style size=\"" + $V{fontSize} + "\">" + $F{name} + "</style>"]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In this case, the text size is specified by a `Integer` variable that is defined in the report but it could equally come from another field or report parameter.

```
<variable name="fontSize" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[12]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

This allows you to do some clever things like varying the text size depending on the length of the field:

```
<variable name="fontSize" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}.length()]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

You can see that the font size of the names below the images is based on the length of the name:

[image: dynamic text size]

Answer (score 0):

I am using *iReport 2.0.2* and although I can cut and paste the above and make it work, when I attempt my own version from scratch it does not work.

What I ended up doing is creating two fields overlaying each other with opposed print when expressions. I determined that given the length of the box that 57 characters would display correctly at 10 pt font.

My resulting print when expressions ended up like this:

```
Box 1 ($F{DATA1}.length() >= 58 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE)  (font size is lowered)
Box 2 ($F{DATA1}.length() < 58 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE)   (10 pt font size)
```

I know this isn't elegant but it works. After a few days of trying to get the Style to work and failing, I looked at other options and settled on this one.

I hope the style works for you but if not this might be a good plan B.