# How to change iReport font as parameter

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

i have application that generate report with custom font style, like font family, color,size and style(bold,italic,underline). And i use all font-family from Windows System.

I try to use parameter in .jrxml file. Like this :
`<parameter name="fontFamily" class="java.awt.Font"/>`

And in the text :

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement uuid="3c9d8704-dbae-49ed-9787-477ff5b8742f" x="4" y="4" width="241" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
             <font fontName="$P{fontFamily}" size="11" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>

        <text><![CDATA[Hasil Pemeriksaan PROCEDURE]]></text>
</staticText>
```

When i preview in iReport, it log error :

```
Error filling print... Font '$P{fontFamily}' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details. 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.awt.Font.<init>(java.lang.String)      
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2730)      
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1676)      
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.prompt.Prompter$1.run(Prompter.java:278)      
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)      
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)      
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)      
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)      
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)      
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)      
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)      
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)      
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)      
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)      
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)      
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)      
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)      
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)      
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Please help me, Thank you before :)

Comment: you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738431/jasperreports-change-font-size-by-param-value

Comment: @fanjavaid Try to use [conditional styles](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles)

Comment: I second Alex's recommendation of conditional styles, but I wonder if $P! would work: <font fontName=$P!{fontFamily} size="11" isBold="true"/> and your input would be "Arial" or "Times New Roman" so that the quotation marks come in with the font name.

Comment: @AlexK I already read about Conditional Styles for your link. But i wonder, i just change the Font style, what condition should i make? Because i just want to change title in the report. Thank you ^^

Comment: @Lisa Yes, i hope like that. But i get Exception in the above.

Comment: Did you try $P! instead of $P alone?

Comment: @Lisa I already try, but wont work. And i just have idea ,i decide use external template file .jrtx and i updated the value like : fontName, fontSize etc using String replace from .java file. And I don't need to make custom in .jrxml file ^^,

Answer (score 1):

Set the following properties

```
Markup : html
Text field expression : "<font face='" + $P{fontName} + "'>" + $F{field1} + "</font>"
```

I can see the difference after I set the value of $P{fontName} to *Monospaced* and *SansSerif*.